# Split string into n segment and ignoring line break?

Tags: javascript

I want to split my string into a segment for every 3 character, here my snippet example

```js
let a = "abcdef"; //length 6
let b = `a
b
c
d
e
f`; // length 11 including line break

console.log(a.match(/.{1,3}/g));
console.log(b.match(/.{1,3}/g));
```

The result from `var a` is fine but when i add line break into each character like `var b` is wrong, why it splitting each char on `var b`? I want the result to be like this:

```js
[
    `a{line_break}b`,
    `{line_break}c{line_break}`,
    `d{line_break}e`,
    `{line_break}f`
]
```

Comment: What's your desired result? `a\nb\nc` as an item, or `a\nb` as an item?

Comment: Or `a\r\n` or `a\r\nb\r\nc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` doesn't match a newline by default. For that, use the `s` flag:

```js
let b = `a
b
c
d
e
f`; // length 11 including line break

console.log(b.match(/.{1,3}/gs));
```

Or match `[\s\S]`, if your environments don't support `/s`:

```js
let b = `a
b
c
d
e
f`; // length 11 including line break

console.log(b.match(/[\s\S]{1,3}/g));
```